# Backup sql database to Google drive using jobs

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, database-backups

How to set up a sql job for automatic backup for a sql database (Database name: Test) to a Google drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the Google
2. Next, you can see to https://sqlbackupandftp.com/ or https://sqlbak.com/ or anything else tool
3. Or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135662/backup-sql-server-to-google-drive

Good luck